# using PowerShell to create automated systens

Tags: powershell, windows-services, automated-tests

I'm looking forward to develop an automated notification and logging-off system that 
notifies and logs off accounts from a computer. So far I planned an example when a class is 
scheduled, except accounts that are registered on the scheduled class. It may 
notify the logged-in users a certain period of time before the class time and 
log them off just before the class time. Or, it could limit their access, for 
example to the printer once the class has started.

So my Question is can I use PowerShell to develop this project ? How far can it be useful, or I should think about using python!

Thanks Fellas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure PowerShell brings anything special to the party. What you are talking about would require a PowerShell session running in the background and perhaps even tying into some sort of eventing, perhaps with the timer class. It might be just as easy to automate something using the task scheduler. At the appointed time check the logged on user and if they don't meet the requirement log them off. You could use PowerShell to create the tasks and handle the processing or any other language really.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite sure yet how to figure that out! but sure that was helpful! I was given these requirements, and I have a very limited skill on scripting!